# Stop MediaElement / MediaTimeline playback

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a MediaElement and MediaTimeline defined as follows. The MediaTimeline is used to loop the video.

It plays perfectly. But I can't figure out how to do the opposite - stop the video and unload the file.

I've already tried the following:

```
mediaElement1.Stop();
mediaElement1.Close();

mediaElement1.Source = null;
mediaTimeline1.Source = null;
```

None of these work. The video still plays.

What is the correct solution?

```
<MediaElement Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="mediaElement1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Stretch="Uniform">

    <MediaElement.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>

                        <!-- The MediaTimeline has a RepeatBehavior="Forever" which makes the media play
             over and over indefinitely.-->
                        <MediaTimeline Name="mediaTimeline1" Source="media\video.mp4" Storyboard.TargetName="mediaElement1"  
         RepeatBehavior="Forever" />

                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </MediaElement.Triggers>

</MediaElement>
```

Comment: Have you tried to stop the `Storyboard`? (something like this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-control-a-storyboard-after-it-starts)